# How does the Java Persistance API handle binary data?

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence

I'm working on a CDN project in Java EE using the Java Persistence API. As such, I'll need to store binary data.

How is that supported? Will I have to store a filename and do read and write operations separately, or can it handle binary data natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @Lob annotation as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html). The example uses a String but if you do like the below example it will store binary data as well.

```
@Lob 
public byte[] getBinaryData() {
    return binaryData;
}
```